# Xcode 8: fix for error (has no member 'backgroundColor')

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

Just trying to set the background color of the button but I keep getting the following error in Xcode 8.3.3.

**Value of type '(UIButton) -> ()' has no member 'backgroundColor'**

Screenshot of the error from xcode

[image]

Comment: Remove the braces after the declaration of your button.

Comment: Your "sampleButton" is an action, not an outlet.

Comment: First of all: please don't post screenshots of your code, paste the code into your question. Concerning your problem: `sampleButton` is not a `UIButton` but a function for handling button presses, which of course has no background color. You need a proper button variable, e.g. `@IBOutlet var sampleButton: UIButton!`.

Comment: Because `(UIButton) -> ()` is closure passing UIButton inside and not actual `UIButton`...

Comment: @dr_barto
Thanks! you were right. I created a outlet and the background color was applied.
About the screenshot, I added it to show the error. Should have added the code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the outlet of the buttons to edit its properties. What you have got is a action of that button for the a particular event like `touchUpInside`.

You should get the Outlet of the button like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var sampleButton: UIButton!
```

and then set the `backgroundColor` in the `viewDidLoad()` :

```
sampleButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
```